# Gesture Recognizer Value Reset

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, uigesturerecognizer

I've a View with a simple image with adds a Rotation and Pinch gesture recognizer (adds from objects library). I've used 2 basic simple lines with 2 IBAction for rotating and zooming the image. All work fine but the problem is this: Each gesture reset the other value. If i rotates the image and after i do a pinch, the value of rotation return to normal and viceversa. I want keep the value for rotation and zoom. I hope was clear the problem. thanks to all. here the code:

```
//  ImageController.swift
//  SpImage
//
//  Created by Ronny Westwood on 06/09/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 RW2017. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ImageController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var Image: UIImageView!

/// IMAGE OUTLET

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func rotationImage(_ sender: UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {
        Image.transform = view.transform.rotated(by: sender.rotation)
    }

    @IBAction func zoomImage(_ sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
        Image.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: sender.scale, y: sender.scale)
    }

/// IMAGE ROTATION & IMAGE ZOOM

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

here the view:
[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQB3n.jpg)

Comment: Please try 'requireGestureRecognizerToFail'    for example as below

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]init];
    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pin = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc]init];
    [tap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:pin];

Comment: first of all, you should include the code that you already have..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation. Minimal, complete, verifiable example applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: hello Gagan, is the same thing the  : func shouldBeRequiredToFail(by: UIGestureRecognizer) because with your example i receive a lot of error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem with this code. all work fine

```
class ImageController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    var delegate: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate?

    @IBOutlet weak var Image: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func rotationImage(_ gestureRecognizer : UIRotationGestureRecognizer)
    {
        if gestureRecognizer.state == .began || gestureRecognizer.state == .changed
        {
           gestureRecognizer.view?.transform = (gestureRecognizer.view?.transform.rotated(by: gestureRecognizer.rotation))!
           gestureRecognizer.rotation = 0.0;
        }
    }

    @IBAction func zoomImage(_ gestureRecognizer : UIPinchGestureRecognizer)
    {
        if gestureRecognizer.state == .began || gestureRecognizer.state == .changed
        {
           gestureRecognizer.view?.transform = (gestureRecognizer.view?.transform.scaledBy(x: gestureRecognizer.scale, y: gestureRecognizer.scale))!
           gestureRecognizer.scale = 1.0;
        }
    }

/// IMAGE ROTATION & IMAGE SCALE

    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool
    {
        return true
    }

/// ALLOW SIMULTANEOUS GESTURES DELEGATE

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

(yes, is the code from AppleDeveloper about the GestureRecognizer)
thank to all. 
another brick on the code.